# Can't load the html page from node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

History / Context: Display the html page from node.js

Problem Statement: The database is connected, but when i am running it in local host it is showing **'Cannot GET'**.

Expected Result: It should load the html page from node.js

Present Output: Database is connected but cant load the page of html

Attach Code:

**filter.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    filter = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(filter),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

server.listen(7550, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:7550/');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/filter_CheckBoxSchema', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('What happened!!!');
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to mongodb!');
    }
});

var filter_CheckBoxSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    category: { name: String, type: Boolean, default: false },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var Filter = mongoose.model('Filter', filter_CheckBoxSchema);
filter.get('example.html', function (req, res) {    
    new Filter({
        name: req.body.name,
        type: req.body.gender,

    }).save(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else
            res.send('Successfully inserted!!!');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Please enter your details
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Please enter your details</h3>
        <p>Please register below!!!</p>

        <form action="filter.js" method="POST">
            Name: <input type="text" name="Name" />
            <br /><p></p>

            Gender:
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="gender" /> Male
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="gender" /> Female
            <p></p>
            Interest: (Check all that apply)
            <p>
            </p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="breakfast" /> Breakfast
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Lunch" /> Lunch
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Evening Snacks" /> Evening Snacks
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Dinner" /> Dinner
            <br />
            <p></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register!!!" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: change the `filter.get("example.html",...` to `filter.get("/example.html",...`

Comment: @fmodos: Sorry sir still not working...

Comment: hmm... so check your node.js server log for some error, if no error put some console.log in the node.js to check if the function is being called

Comment: Done but same error is coming...i dont know what to do...please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors here:

1. You should define your routes from root '/'. That means that if you want to print "hi" on 127.0.0.1:7550/hi    you'll write:

   app.get('/hi', function(req,res){
       res.send('hi');
   });
2. To serve static files you should use the express.static middleware.

   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Try generating a sample express application and see how it is structured: https://github.com/expressjs/generator